# Adding LibreOffice Official Repository for Updates

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade, libreoffice, lmde, linux-libre

I use Linux Mint LMDE2 64bit OS. The version of LibreOfice that is installed on my PC is 4.3.3.2. Even with

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I don't get any updates. I know that I can simply download the deb file from Official site and install it right away but I also want regular updates for this. Is there anyway that I can add the repository of LibreOffice so that I can get regular updates with simple commands. I don't really want to check on it again and again to see if some new update has come and then uninstall the previous version and install the new version. Is there anyway to do it ??

Comment: have you installed necessary ppa for libreoffice ?

Comment: See [LibreOffice PPA](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

Comment: LMDE doesn't support PPA.

Comment: maybe ask libreoffice to also support repositories for debian...!?